# How to set customized tab colors in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 it was possible to choose an individual tab color for each project using the addon "Productivity Power Tools", see also http://dev.goshoom.net/2020/08/colored-tabs-in-visual-studio/

Although Visual Studio 2022 offers a possibility to enable tab colors by project (menu Tools > Options > Tabs & Windows, and enable Colorize Tabs), it looks as if the color that is assigned to each project can't be chosen by the user. Does anybody know if there's any other way to choose it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2022 the colors for the project tabs are not fixed and can be set by the user after enabling tab color first (Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs & Windows, and enable Colorize Tabs)

You can then set the color from some predetermined options by right clicking on a file tab then selecting (Select Tab Color > YOUR COLOR CHOICE)

Comment: I assume that this is a feature that's been introduced recently from VS2022. Although Productivity Power Tools allowed to assign the color using a HEX code, at least now we can choose from 16 colors

Comment: I was looking for this and when opening Options it is under environment.

Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs & Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension to choose an individual tab color for each project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The colours are fixed.

There is a feedback item requesting more flexibility: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/color-coded-tabs-in-visual-studio/351700